# Compile time testfor 'atoms'

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

Completely new to prolog. Interesting journey so far in trying to change how I think, so appreciate any help here.

I am trying to assert facts for a pre-defined set of names. For example, assume I have a a set of people [alice, bob, ...] in one file. I would like to assert facts about these folks in other files, but want to make sure that these folks exist and that is checked when the facts are loaded/compiled(?).

For example, assume I don't have 'chuck' in the list and I make an assertion:

user: swipl app.pl

```
?- full_name(chuck, "Charlie Steel").
```

should result in an error.

What is the best way I can do this?

Comment: The trick here is probably to open the file and use `read/2` to obtain Prolog terms from the file, then examine them; if they pass, use `assertz/1` to add them to the store, if they do not pass, then report an error. I'm going to try and gin something up but take a crack at it yourself and maybe you'll get there first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here's the code I came up with:

```
person(deborah).
person(tony).

read_my_file(Filename) :-
    open(Filename, read, In),
    read_my_file1(In),
    close(In).

read_my_file1(In) :-
    read(In, Term),
    (  Term == end_of_file
    -> true
    ;  assert_or_abort(Term),
       read_my_file1(In)
    ).

assert_or_abort(Term) :-
    (  full_name(Person, Name) = Term
    ->  (  person(Person)
        -> assertz(full_name(Person, Name))
        ;  format(user, '~w is not a person I recognize~n', [Person])
        )
    ;  format(user, '~w is not a term I know how to parse~n', [Term])
    ).
```

The trick here is using `read/2` to obtain a Prolog term from the stream, and then doing some deterministic tests of it, hence the nested conditional structure inside `assert_or_abort/1`. Supposing you have an input file that looks like this:

```
full_name(deborah, 'Deborah Ismyname').
full_name(chuck, 'Charlie Steel').
full_name(this, has, too, many, arguments).
squant.
```

You get this output:

```
?- read_my_file('foo.txt').
chuck is not a person I recognize
full_name(this,has,too,many,arguments) is not a term I know how to parse
squant is not a term I know how to parse
true.

?- full_name(X,Y).
X = deborah,
Y = 'Deborah Ismyname'.
```